# Prove that a square of a positive integer cannot end with $4$ same digits different from $0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion, square-numbers

Prove that a square of a positive integer cannot end with $4$ same digits different from $0$.

I already proved that square of positive integer cannot end with none of digits $1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9$ using the remainder of division by $3,4,8,10$. Now problem is how to prove that this number cannot end with $4444$.

Comment: Integers whose squares end $444$ are of the form $500k\pm38$ and these squares all have an odd digit immediately before the $444$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that a number $x\in \mathbb N$ suffices $x^2\mod 10000 = 4444$.
Notice that only the 4 least significat digits of $x$ are important for computing $x^2\mod 10000$, so denote by $a,b,c,d$ digits such that:
$$x\mod 10000 = 1000a+100b+10c+d$$

Next, notice that:
$$x^2 \mod 10000 = 1000(2ad+2bc)+100(2bd+c^2)+10(2cd)+d^2 \mod 10000$$

This gives us a set of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
      d^2 = 4 \\
      2cd = 4\\
      2bd + c^2 = 4\\ 
      2ad+2bc = 4\\ 
   \end{cases} $$

Since there is no solution for this equation set (for $a,b,c,d\in\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$), no such integer $x$ exists.

Comment: Why $d^2=4$? If, for example, $d=8$ then $d^2=64$, but $(d^2\mod10)=4$ and then $((2cd+d^2-(d^2\mod10))\mod10)=4$ etc. But then this system of equations become more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As $x^2=4444\equiv12 \pmod{ 16}$, so no squares can end in four $4$'s.